# How to embed google groups to a web page

Tags: php, javascript, google-groups

I have created a google group by the name "bessah" and i want to embed it to my web page

Comment: That's nice. Good luck!

Comment: my quistion is how embed it to my web page

Comment: print out the group, put printout on a wooden table, take digital photo of printout, put photo into web page.

Comment: here is my comment http://paste.ubuntu.com/6180463/ please read!

Answer (score 3):

Using HTML IFRAMEs provides an easy way to customize your own site with a discussion forum and Embed Google Group.
The simplest approach to adding a forum to your site is to create an IFRAME that points to Google Group.

https://sites.google.com/site/embeddingdiscussions/using-iframes

Comment: This link is broken.  Can you update?

Comment: Ben Gripka.The Iframe do not work well for many sites these days. This is very old answer. Here is general idea https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/html-iframes.php