# How to embed Google Groups forum into web page using iframe?

Tags: iframe, embedding, google-groups

I fear I have the same challenge as a previous posters:

[Embedding a Google Group - nothing is displayed when not logged into Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835937/embedding-a-google-group-nothing-is-displayed-when-not-logged-into-google#new-answer?newreg=e1df654b49914581ad896400b6b77b5f)

and 
[How to embed google groups to a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819444/how-to-embed-google-groups-to-a-web-page)

The first resolved, but the second unresolved.

Would like to embed a google-group forum into an html page.  I am unable to do that following guidance provided by Google Groups using `iframe`:

```
<iframe id="forum_embed"
        src="javascript:void(0)"
        scrolling="no"
        frameborder="0"
        width="900"
        height="700">
</iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById('forum_embed').src =
 'https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum/test-distance'
 + '&showsearch=true&showpopout=true&showtabs=false'
 + '&parenturl=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
</script>
```

and successfully shown by http://www.jqcoolgallery.com/support.html.  I can view this embedded forum, but when applying the same syntax in my html, I do not have success.

I have the same lack of success when viewing either in Firefox 27 or in Internet Explorer 11.

Answer (score 0):

your example works fine for me, [see this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/puravida/q7wq4/)

complete example code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<div>
  <iframe id="forum_embed"
        src="javascript:void(0)"
        scrolling="no"
        frameborder="0"
        width="900"
        height="700">
  </iframe>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById('forum_embed').src =
 'https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum/test-distance'
 + '&showsearch=true&showpopout=true&showtabs=false'
 + '&parenturl=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
  </script>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**screenshot**:
[image]

Comment: Attempted to use this code on my machine without success.  Page loads without error but shows empty page without content.

Comment: [this page](http://puravidaapps.com/forum.php) uses the same code, does this work for you? Probably a browser problem? Which browser are you using? I just added a screenshot of the jsfidde how it looks like using Windows 7 and Chrome

Comment: Seems like this worked a while ago, but now when I visit the jsfiddle , I see a message, "Embedded groups are no longer supported. To view this group, visit Google Groups. Learn more".

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe id="forum_embed" src="https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum/NAMEOFYOURGROUP#!forum/NAMEOFYOURGROUP" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="700"></iframe>
```

This will work for you as it did for me.
Yes NAMEOFYOURGROUP appears twice on that iframe.
Don't forget to change NAMEOFYOURGROUP to your group name.

Comment: This may have worked in the past, but as of 2021 Google Groups no longer supports embedding, at least not in this manner.